# How to predict future with tensotflow lib

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, predict

I use the [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) library to solve the time series problem.
I get the dimensions or properties by subtracting the current value from the previous value ([according to this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-sales-611cb5a252de))
In this article, there is the data needed for forecasting. It chooses a value for training and a value for testing that there are no problems.
But my question is how can I predict the future? Suppose if I want to forecast 5 months later there will be no dimensions or attributes to send to the forecast function.

--If you have a better source, please introduce it ...Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a lot of data it could be possible, it means that your model knows a lot of data and can generalize with new data and it can find a knowed pattern. If you have a poor model it will throws bad predictions because the new input is new and the model can't find a knowed pattern